# Find all files that weren't unzipped

Tags: shell, grep, zip, ls

I have a folder that contains several zipped folders, I tried to unzip them but some trowed errors but since there are a lot of folders I can't seem to find which ones were not unzipped, my folder looks like this:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 bruno bruno     36864 abr  3 21:18 00059285000136
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bruno bruno   1618361 abr  3 19:55 00059285000136.zip
drwxr-xr-x 2 bruno bruno     12288 abr  3 21:18 00059289000114
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bruno bruno    483970 abr  3 19:55 00059289000114.zip
drwxr-xr-x 2 bruno bruno     12288 abr  3 21:18 00059292000138
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bruno bruno    494923 abr  3 19:55 00059292000138.zip
drwxr-xr-x 2 bruno bruno     20480 abr  3 21:18 00059563000155
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bruno bruno    890522 abr  3 19:55 00059563000155.zip
drwxr-xr-x 2 bruno bruno     73728 abr  3 21:18 00059564000108
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bruno bruno   3216973 abr  3 19:55 00059564000108.zip
drwxr-xr-x 2 bruno bruno     20480 abr  3 21:18 00067859000118
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bruno bruno    905108 abr  3 19:55 00067859000118.zip
drwxr-xr-x 2 bruno bruno     49152 abr  3 21:18 00067860000142
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bruno bruno   2130747 abr  3 19:55 00067860000142.zip
drwxr-xr-x 2 bruno bruno     20480 abr  3 21:18 00068070000181
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bruno bruno    750779 abr  3 19:55 00068070000181.zip
drwxr-xr-x 2 bruno bruno      4096 abr  3 21:18 00068071000126
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bruno bruno      8595 abr  3 19:55 00068071000126.zip
drwxr-xr-x 2 bruno bruno     12288 abr  3 21:18 00073134000132
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bruno bruno    347212 abr  3 19:55 00073134000132.zip
drwxr-xr-x 2 bruno bruno     20480 abr  3 21:18 00073135000187
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bruno bruno    779648 abr  3 19:55 00073135000187.zip
drwxr-xr-x 2 bruno bruno      4096 abr  3 21:18 00073136000121
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bruno bruno    226300 abr  3 19:55 00073136000121.zip
drwxr-xr-x 2 bruno bruno     12288 abr  3 21:18 00074485000168
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bruno bruno    496361 abr  3 19:55 00074485000168.zip
drwxr-xr-x 2 bruno bruno     20480 abr  3 21:18 00083506000101
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bruno bruno    741531 abr  3 19:55 00083506000101.zip
drwxr-xr-x 2 bruno bruno     12288 abr  3 21:18 00084530000165
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bruno bruno    479596 abr  3 19:55 00084530000165.zip
drwxr-xr-x 2 bruno bruno     12288 abr  3 21:18 00088714000101
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bruno bruno    462495 abr  3 19:55 00088714000101.zip
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bruno bruno    682841 abr  3 19:55 00109143000136.zip
```

Is there any command to find which ones aren't unzipped? All the unzipped folders and they zipped pair have the same name (except the .zip).

Comment: In the example, it looks like `00109143000136.zip` is the only file that was not unzipped.  Are you asking for a command that will print that one name (in this example)?  If not, what is the desired output for this example?

Comment: Sorry, I think I didn't explain but that is just a sample of the data, there's a lot more folders, that one you said is just one example that wasn't unzipped. Yes, I would like to know if there exist a command that could print all the "problematic" zip files @ScottMcPeak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the question is how to report every file `NAME.zip` file for which `NAME` does not exist.  This script will do that:

```
#!/bin/sh

for fn in *.zip; do
  # Remove the trailing ".zip".
  base=$(echo "$fn" | sed 's/\.zip$//')

  if [ ! -e "$base" ]; then
    # The corresponding name without ".zip" does not exist.
    echo "$fn"
  fi
done
```

Example run:

```
$ ls
1  1.zip  2  2.zip  3.zip  4.zip  5  5.zip  find-not-zipped.sh*

$ ./find-not-zipped.sh
3.zip
4.zip
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was searching! Thanks